# shows number of successfully uploaded files in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, file-upload

I am using  [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to upload multple files dynamically to server.Everything works fine but i want show number of successfully uploaded files.
Here is the code

```
.controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', function($scope, FileUploader) {
        var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
            url: 'upload.php'
        });
 uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            console.info('onCompleteItem',response);

        };
})
```

Here is my php file

```
<?php
  //setup function upload_file() for upload files
  if(upload_file()){
     echo 'success';
  }else{
   echo 'error';
}
?>
```

How can i show number of successfully uploaded files after completing file upload?

Comment: Do you just want to keep track of how many files the user has uploaded whilst they have been using the application - so on a per visit basis?

Comment: i just want to get the number of successfully uploaded files

Comment: Can't you just set a variable in the onCompleteItem handler function, so increment a counter? Do you need to know the number of files uploaded from other parts of your application?